# Implementing a protocol specific method in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

Given an Objective-C class `MyClass` which communicates with an API/Datalayer/external-something via a class `Connection`, `MyClass` should either (depending on surrounding arch) receive and instance of `Connection` in the constructor or an instance of `Connection` should be passed to each method call which requires a connection. This way `MyClass` can encapsulate application logic and remain ignorant of the connection details.

To reuse the logic in `MyClass` with different external components or to unit-test `MyClass`, it is proper to use a protocol (`ConnectionProtocol`) instead of a class `Connection`. This way, different classes (say ConnectionHttp, ConnnectionAPI2, ConnectionTestingEmulateProxyIssue, for instance) can be used with `MyClass` as long as they implement `ConnectionProtocol`.

Now, assume the developer has a block of code which is repeated in `MyClass`, `MyOtherClass`, and  which performs a series of operations with `ConnectionProtocol`. This violates the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle and is therefore unacceptable.

1. Since `MyClass`, `MyOtherClass`, and  do not share a common base class (other than NSObject), the developer cannot simply merge the functionallity into a base class.
2. Adding a method to `ConnectionProtocol` violates [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) again as the functionality needs to be repeated in each implementation of `ConnectionProtocol`.
3. Making the method an `@optional` member of `ConnectionProtocol` still does not work because

   - the method is used frequently and will need to be implemented in each implementation and
   - the method logic is specific to the application, not the connection violating [SoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).
4. The developer considers adding a category to NSObject which checks if the passed object implements protocol `ConnectionProtocol` and then performs the required operations. This has drawbacks:

   - The method space for NSObject is polluted for all objects in the files in which the category is used,
   - Errors in which the category method is invoked incorrectly are caught a runtime and the developer picked a strongly typed language for a reason
5. **`ConnectionProtocol` is extended using a category. This does not violate the DRY principle and respects SoC. It does however violate the Objective-C specification.**

   ```
   @implementation id< ConnectionProtocol > (AppLogicMethods)

   -(void)specialMethod:(NSObject*)myParam
   {
       // Do Stuff  
   }

   @end
   ```

How does one go about solving this problem without violating [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), respecting [SoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), and meeting the limitations of Objective-C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This violates the DRY principle and is therefore unacceptable.

DRY is not an unassailable Law of Nature. It's not even a felony in most US states. It is a piece of useful design guidance and should be weighed against other useful design guidance such as simplicity and avoidance of [SAAAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_at_a_distance_%28computer_programming%29). I have seen many projects become far too over-complicated for fear of repeating a couple of lines of trivial code. Clarity is more important than brevity. Magic is worse than WET.

That said, DRY is a useful piece of guidance, and I think we can incorporate it appropriately here.

> Now, assume the developer has a block of code which is repeated in MyClass, MyOtherClass, and which performs a series of operations with ConnectionProtocol.

This suggests that there are higher-level operations that are independent of the actual transport ("block of code which is repeated…and which performs a series of operations with ConnectionProtocol"). That suggests you're abstracting at the wrong level. You have a lower-level transport ("HTTP") and you have a higher-level thing called a "Connection" that manages that transport. So there should be a concrete class `Connection` that HAS-A `<Transport>`, and `MyClass` would HAS-A `Connection`.

That said, I would be slow to create this `<Transport>` protocol. I would start with the `Connection` class that includes the transport logic. If the only problem I had to solve was unit testing, I'd probably just subclass `Connection` for that rather than inject complexity. If non-test problems came up, then I would refactor to add the extra layer. Adding too many layers too early is a common way to overcomplicate a codebase, and complexity is a worse enemy of robustness than repeating yourself.

As a side note: your answer using class methods to package common code is also a very reasonable approach, and may be simpler for some uses.

Comment: "It's not even a felony in most US states." Nice job picking up on the satire but maintaining a purist perspective in the answer.

Comment: This answer strikes me as correct because the root of the problem is that there is a third layer between MyClass and the Connection class sighted in the question (third layer naming will be different as it's app-logic and Connection already HAS-A Transport). My context switch between C#/Obj-C told me this should be implemented as a collection of categories (still wish Obj-C had "categories" on protocols) but a C++ architectural style of a new class with a HAS-A meets the architect's purity test and is therefore probably the correct Obj-C architectural style.

Answer (score 0):

A "utility class" is created into which the `ConnectionProtocol` and `myParam` are passed.

```
@implementation ConnectionProtocolAppLogicMethods

+(void)specialMethod:(NSObject*)myParam connection:(id<ConnectionProtocol>)connection
{
    // Do Stuff
}

@end
```